# CSS stop drop down menu from disappearing when hovering on items

Tags: css, html

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a>Hello</a>
      <ul>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
        <li>item</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

CSS:

```
*{
  list-style: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav-item{
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
    .nav-item >a{
      background: gray;
      width: 100px;
      text-align: center;
      display: inline-block;
    }
    .nav-item > ul{
        position: relative;
        display: none;
        width: 100px;
    }
      .nav-item > ul > li{
        background: yellow;
        opacity: 0.4;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
      }
    .nav-item > a:hover + ul{
        display: block;
    }
    .nav-item > ul :hover {
      display: block;
    }
```

The problem is that when i hover on drop down menu it closes,how do i prevent it?I tried using

```
    .nav-item > ul :hover {
      display: block;
    }
```

to not hide it when hovering on it,but it doesn't fix the problem.I tried to google but i cant find any solutions,please help me.Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing the space between `ul` and `:hover`:

```
.nav-item > ul:hover {
  display: block;
}
```

See fiddle [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JGObNr)

Comment: @DoItSimple - you're welcome. If this is what you were looking for you can also mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding:

With the below code you are saying make the UL to `display:block` (within the nav-item) when you hover over it, but in fact it's hidden `.nav-item > ul {display : none}` so how can you hover over it?

```
.nav-item > ul :hover {
  display: block;
}
```

If you remove the UL from this and keep it as below, even this works.

```
.nav-item :hover {
  display: block;
}
```

Note: If you want to modify an element based on other element, you should use jquery.